# Permission denied issue while using autopytoexe

Tags: python, exe, data-conversion, auto-py-to-exe

I'm trying to convert a python file into an .exe, but I systematically get the following error:

```
    An error occurred while packaging
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\auto_py_to_exe\packaging.py", line 131, in package
    run_pyinstaller()
  File "c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 114, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 65, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 720, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 667, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "C:\Users\NAME\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpfe6m2e7t\myprog.spec", line 37, in <module>
    name='myprog')
  File "c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 701, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 160, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 745, in assemble
    shutil.copy(fnm, tofnm)
  File "c:\program files\python37\lib\shutil.py", line 241, in copy
    copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "c:\program files\python37\lib\shutil.py", line 120, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'config\\SOFTWARE'
```

I tried to start autopytoexe as an admin, and to move the file into another directory but that didn't change anything.
I also tried to convert other (more basic) files and the conversion worked properly, so maybe the problem comes from the modules I am using ? (matplotlib, scipy, numpy and others that I wrote myself also based on these three modules)

If anybody has an idea of what might cause this issue and how to solve it...

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please provide a [mre] of the code and steps that can be used to reliably reproduce the issue. See [ask]